# Writing scripts using Wordpress / WooCommerce classes?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, scripts

I have various processing scripts I want to run that modify WooCommerce order data. Currently, I build the scripts as a function in my theme's functions.php and then attach the function to a shortcode. I then build a page in Wordpress that just contains that shortcode and load the page in my browser to execute the script.

That seems incredibly convoluted and there has to be a "proper" way to do this that doesn't involve creating pages and running things through the theme.

I need access to things like WP_Query and the WooCommerce Order class, but essentially would like to have the full Wordpress and WooCommerce classes/functions available to me, just like they are when I run things through pages/shortcodes.

Is there a proper way to easily bootstrap all the Wordpress includes, without having to go all the way through the theme?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a proper way to easily bootstrap all the Wordpress includes,
>   without having to go all the way through the theme?

That's the wrong question. Shortcodes are *far* from the only way to run code from a theme or plugin. You've correctly identified them as inappropriate for the job though. What I think you should be looking to do is to find a better way to run your scripts from a theme or plugin.

The way I see it, you have 2 main options, basically depending on how your want your script to be triggered.

If you want to **manually trigger** the script, then you should create a page in the admin with a button that triggers the script. The basic steps for that would be:

1. Use [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) to add the page to the admin somewhere.
2. For the contents of the page output a form with the `action` set to `<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ) ); ?>` and a hidden input with the `name"action"` and `value` as a unique identifier for your functionality.
3. Add a hook to `admin_post_{whatever your action name is}` that runs your script.

[This tutorial](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/handling-form-submissions/) on admin forms covers the topic in more detail.

Now you'll have a place in the admin where you can go and push a button to run your scripts.

If you want to **automatically trigger** the scripts **on a schedule**, then you should use WP Cron to schedule the script function to run. The documentation for that is [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/scheduling-wp-cron-events/), but essentially rather than adding your script function to a shortcode with `add_shortcode()`, add the function to a hook with `add_action()`, then use `wp_schedule_event()` to schedule the action to run at certain times.

You can use `wp_next_scheduled()` to automatically schedule the script to run again after each time it runs:

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( '{whatever your hook name is}' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', '{whatever your hook name is}', $args );
}
```